# include html code inside php with determine variable

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP code which sends an email with HTML template.
HTML template has some PHP variable like Name, Email, etc.

```
<strong>Name: {name} </strong>
```

because email template has more code, I include it in my PHP file

```
$htmlInvoice = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/mail/invoice.html');

$name= $user['name']);

$msg = $htmlInvoice;
```

But when an email sent, it can not read variables inside the 
HTML file. and for example echo `$name` like a text

Comment: That would be because you haven't told it to do anything with `$htmlInvoice`, such as string replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strtr` for this. For e.g:

```
<?php

$a = 'Hi this is {name}. I am writing {language}';

echo strtr($a, ['{name}' => 'Abhishek', '{language}' => 'php']);
```

[Strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the {name} string for your desired output.

```
$htmlInvoice = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/mail/invoice.html');

$name= $user['name']);

$msg = str_replace('{name}',$name, $htmlInvoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change /mail/invoice.html to include PHP commands.

```
<strong><? echo $user['name'] ?></strong>
```

Then

```
$htmlInvoice = file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] .'/mail/invoice.html');

$msg = _readphp_eval($htmlInvoice);

function _readphp_eval($code) {
  ob_start();
  print eval('?>'. $code);
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $output;
}
```

I don't know who to attribute _readphp_eval($code) function to ... It is floating around the internet, and works very nicely for this purpose.

It would require that $user['name'] be defined/included in the invoice.html file.